# Extracting word embedding features of a sentence using Transformer-XL

Tags: tensorflow, word-embeddings, word2vec, embeddings

As you know, there are several pre-trained models that we can use to extract word embeddings.

As an example, I can use the following codes to retrieve word2vec features of my text:

```
import gensim
from gensim.models import Word2Vec

word2vec_model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('./data/word_embeddings/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True)

def retrieve_word2vec(word):
    return word2vec_model.wv[word]
```

Currently, I am interested to extract word features using pre-trained [transformer-XL](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.02860) models. Is there any sample code to understand how to do that? (I couldn't find something useful by myself).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're asking specifically about `gensim`, and this question will likely be closed (generally questions about specific libraries aren't accepted) but I really like the Huggingface library and they have a [transformerxl](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/transformerxl.html) implementation. I've not used it but in general I've used the following:

```
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(model_name)
config.output_hidden_states = True
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(model_name, config=config)
model.eval()

def cls_embedding(example):
    inputs=tokenizer(example, return_tensors='pt')
    outputs = model(**inputs)
    return outputs["hidden_states"][-1][-1][0].detach().numpy()
```

Note you probably want `outputs["hidden_states"][-1][-1][:]` if you want an embedding per input token (i.e. contextual embedding)?

Comment: Thank you very much. That is right, I was looking for a sample code to that. 
I understood. But thanks a lot for your help.